# I m trying to find the minimum number but i keep geting the max some some help he?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.text.*;

public class p171ex6a{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numk;
        numk = scan.nextInt();
        double num;
        double [] max = new double[numk];

        for (int in=0;in<numk;in++) {
            num = scan.nextDouble();        
            max [in]= num;
        }

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000"); 
        Arrays.sort(max);   
        System.out.println(df.format(max[max.length-1]));
    }    
}
```

Comment: The number 1 rated user on Stack Overflow just answered your question! Pretty cool, eh? :)

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to find the *minimum* number you should be printing out the *first* element of the array, not the *last* one... because the array is sorted in *ascending* order.

```
System.out.println(df.format(max[0]));
```

The array name is an odd one here - something like `values` would be more appropriate. I'd also declare variables at the point of first use:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int valueCount = scanner.nextInt();
double[] values = new double[valueCount];

for (int i = 0; i < valueCount; i++)
{
    values[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
}

Arrays.sort(values);

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
System.out.println(formatter.format(values[0]));
```